# How to connect strings in MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab, concatenation, strcat

I try to do the following:

```
fname = strcat('C:\Users\user_name\work\video\',avi_name);
videoObject = VideoReader(fname);
```

I get an error message:

```
Argument must contain a string.
```

I try to check what is my `fname`:

```
fname = strcat('C:\Users\user_name\work\video\',avi_name);
fname
videoObject = VideoReader(fname);
```

I see that it is (as expected):

```
'C:\Users\user_name\work\video\bla_bla.avi'
```

When I try to do the following:

```
fname = 'C:\Users\user_name\work\video\bla_bla.avi';
videoObject = VideoReader(fname);
```

It works. Can anybody explain me what is wrong with the output of `strcat`. Why it is not recognized as a string by the function and why it does look like a correct string in the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `avi_name` is a cell array, then the output of `strcat` will be a cell array as well (that's why the string comes with quotation marks when you display it).

Use

```
fname = strcat('C:\Users\user_name\work\video\',avi_name{1});
```